# Thread is not interrupted/is not stopping

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a peer-to-peer voice-chat program that is attempting to establish connection between two peers at the beginning of the program.

I have created two threads, one thread `Call` that handles users request to call someone and `receiveCall` that handles incomming calls.

What I want to do is that when you either get a call or call someone is to "kill" the other thread because it served it's purpose.

The method that creates the two threads.

```
public Peer(String[] args) {
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        stateHandler = new StateHandler();
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        call = new Thread(new ReceiveCall());
        call.start();
        receiveCall = new Thread(new Call());
        receiveCall.start();

    }
```

The `Call` method:

```
    class Call implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    System.out.print(">");
                    String ip;
                    int port;
                    DataOutputStream output;
                    String call;

                    call = scanner.nextLine();

                    while (!call.contains("call") && findMatches(call, " ") != 2 && !callFlag) {
                        System.out.println("Usage: call <ip> <port>");
                        call = scanner.nextLine();
                    }

                    String[] parts = call.split(" ");
                    ip = parts[1];
                    port = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

                    socket = new Socket(ip, port);

                    //Send invite
                    output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    output.writeUTF("INVITE");

                    stateHandler.manageStates(StateHandler.StateEvent.CALLING, socket);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }        
        }
    }
```

The `ReceiveCall` method:

```
class ReceiveCall implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        DataInputStream inputStream;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        String answer, msg = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Accept connection
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            call.interrupt(); //Here I want to interrupt the other thread
            inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            msg = inputStream.readUTF();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!msg.equals("INVITE")) {

        }

        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().toString() + " is calling you! Answer? (Y/N)");

        synchronized (scanner) {
            answer = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        if (!answer.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Ready to receive a call or call...");
        }

        try {
            outputStream.writeUTF("TRO");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stateHandler.manageStates(StateHandler.StateEvent.RECEIVE_CALL, socket);

    }
}
```

The program is statebased so when one of the threads complete it is supposed to go to another state and execute the appropriate code there.

Comment: Where does your thread check if it has been interrupted? Remember, Java threading is cooperative: like Robin Williams said of UK police, "stop! Or... I'll say stop again!". Your thread has to check if it has been interrupted to know if it has been interrupted, it doesn't just stop automagically.

Comment: The `Call` method is wrapped inside a while-loop that is checking if it has been interrupted. I beleive that the scanner that is waiting for input is stopping it from checking though...